# WiFi Communication C# and ESP8266

Tags: c#, arduino, wifi, esp8266, remote-control

I'm working on a project and am looking for a way to connect with ESP8266 via WiFi module on ESP8266. I have to build use this method, through the windows desktop I can control the movement of robot. From C# to ESP just like remote control project. I have a lack of knowledge of C# same as basics of servers/internet but I have everything done in Arduino IDE code and control the robot through web browser but I'm stuck on Communication Wifi between C# and ESP866. I need some help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can host a REST API Server in the ESP8266 with the using the [ESP8266WebServer](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer) and use your usual REST Programming in C# like [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) or [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/).

Comment: REST API to control a robot?

Comment: You can expose the robot control via the REST, right?

Comment: but the speed of text processing for xml or json on a MCU will make the robot reactions too slow. TCP/IP is already slow for this

Comment: Im soory but I couldn't understand. I did some coding, but It doesn't work. You may foud where I need to add more coding https://pastebin.com/TedUsgzg

Comment: @Juraj, Yes, but the OP wanted it for his ESP8266 based Robot. This is one of the way. Else he can use a better base controller and hookup the ESP8266 through Serial and only for WiFi connectivity.

Comment: @Adeline, there is beautiful interface SO offer to include code, please use the SO to share the code instead of pastebin.